# Put only one bracket in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, mono

I have a problem. At the time of writing the code in Xamarin Studio when I put the bracket it's only put open, but I would like to put both an open and a closed set. How would I do it?

Comment: Xamarin Studio has been deprecated.  Do you mean Visual Studio for Mac?  And I assume you mean Intellisense/Code Completion is not adding a closing "}" when you type an "{"?  If not, can you explain your problem in clearer detail?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, you use the best and powerful ide from Microsoft,

Visual Studio https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Just click the Mobile .Net Development upon installation and you'll have Visual Studio with Xamarin. :)